# Getting error while connection to oracle in scala

Tags: oracle, scala

I am new to scala, here i am trying to connect to oracle to get the table data. But i am getting the following error. Please advice what needs to be done.

Below is error and code.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException:
>   ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does
>   not exist Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory Additional
>   information: 3651 Additional information: -2130290505

code:

```
 val ods = new OracleDataSource()

    ods.setUser("TM_ODS")

    ods.setPassword("odstm")

    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@db-dfdev:1521/dfdev")

    val con = ods.getConnection()

    println("Connected")
```

Comment: Make sure you properly define ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID parameters for OS where your DB stays.

Comment: Are you able to connect to Oracle remotely from some other tool or CLI, if not trying to add IP_ADDRESS instead of host name.